# Executing the .jar and printing errorlevel

Tags: java, batch-file, jvm

I need help or guidance when running two java programs and trying to read an exit error.

This'll be a little hard to explain so please forgive me if I'm not really clear.

Let's say that the chain of executing is something like this:

1. **bat1.bat** is the start, it execute **myPGM.jar**
2. **myPGM.jar** calls a 2nd bat: **bat2.bat**
3. **bat2.bat** calls an external bat, let's call it: **runProcess.bat**
4. **runProcess.bat** calls an **external .jar** and when it finish, it does **echo errorlevel=%errorlevel%**.

**The problem is that the second .jar is failing** and:

If I run all the chain: bat1.bat -> myPGM.jar -> bat2.bat -> runProcess.bat -> external.jar -> echo...
Although the external jar is failing, **it always prints 0**!

If I pause the execution before the runProcess.bat call, open a new cmd window and call it from there.. **it prints the error correctly**!

I'm really stuck with this, and probably don't have the knowledge to see where the problem is :(

My guess is that the problem can be related to the two java programs running at the same time?.. maybe the second one is like in another instance of a jvm, and that's why the bat always print errorlevel=0?
Or maybe is how I'm calling the .bat? I'm missing a parameter or something like this?

Well, reallyy really thanks!

Comment: Don't know if it's a typo or not but you have written runProces.bat and runProcess.bat ... maybe check you are using the right names/paths for the calls

Comment: Yes, it was a typo. Corrected! thx :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need that? Anyway if you set the any variable in one command line you can not access it from an other.

Comment: But.. I think I didn't understand you haha. What do you mean with the variable? The problem is in the last .bat (runProcess), it does two things: "**call external jar**" and "**echo %ERRORLEVEL%**". If I call all the chain: **bat1** execute **my jar**, **my jar** calls a **bat2**, which calls that **runProcess**.. after the jar, it always **echo 0**! And if I just call the **bat2** from a cmd.. this bat calls the **runProcess**, which after the external jar **echo the error correctly**.

Comment: What I did has changed a lot in the last few weeks, that is why it is like this now. We initally just had **runProcess.bat and external.jar**. They are from an external company, we just call the runProcess with a lot of different parameters. 
My program need to call that jar.. that's why all of that. 
Probably bat2 now is useless.. I can directly call runProcess or even import their .jar and use it. But, as it is external and can change.. It would probably be wise to have their "runProcess.bat + extrenal.jar", I just use it.. no? :)

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Well.. this looks awful. It seems that Spaces and Tabs don't work in comments :(

Comment: Ahhh ok. The external java program set the errorlevel. I just pass it to a txt and read it from there. The issue is that when calling all from my java.. the errorlevel is always 0 (even in the ECHO just after their java). it seems like their java is not setting it right, maybe it's setting like another instance of the %errorlevel%?.. :S:S